# Elementor custom filter query in custom post type template - How to query field value to filter by?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor, acfpro

I have a custom post type which is a sort of profile page for suppliers. On the end of each page, I have a products-widget, which is supposed to show the products of this supplier.

All products are assigned to a supplier-specific category. So profile-page of supplier A should show all products assigned to product_cat A.

The corresponding product_cat is specified by an acf-field on each profile page.
So my custom filter query needs to get the specified product_cat and then filter all products by that category.
I'm struggling on how to get that custom field value from the post into my filter query.
This is what I have so far:

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/my-custom-query', function( $query ) {
    $filtre = get_field( "supplier_cat" );
    $query-> set('product_cat' , $filtre );

} );
```

Comment: 1. Which Products Widget do you use?

2. What is stored in "anzuzeigende_produktkategorie" ?

Comment: Edited for clarity - "anzuzeigende_produktkategorie" (supplier_cat) ist the field that holds the value of type product_cat to filter by. It's an acf field of my custom post type I need to query. I'm using a custom loop template - but any archive / products widget would support the custom filter query.

Comment: Why don't you use a custom field for the supplier in the product post? And filter for them at the supplier detail page? Can you tell me how you managed to get a products loop with a my-custom-query filter? The default WC doesn't support it.

Comment: Because it is a template file, I need the filter query to be dynamic. The widget I use is the posts widget with a custom skin applied.

Comment: So, you want to link the suppliers to specific product_cat and not the products to a supplier? Is `supplier_cat` a single category or an array? Please provide some examples.

Comment: The products are linked to the supplier by the category they are assigned to. My custom post type represents the profile-pages of each supplier. So I have a template for my custom post-type consisting of a series of acf-fields, so the profile-pages are created through a form in the backend. One of those fields is 'supplier_cat' - so it holds the id (or object) of the existing product_cat, that holds the products of this specific supplier. Basically everything is set up - and im utilizing the custom-query-filter, as the term-field cant be set dynamically thorugh acf. (Thanks for your input!)

Comment: Did you try "Advanced Post Queries"? Maybe this helps: youtube.com/watch?v=ZXjTGSUhMps ?

Answer (score 0):

The `get_field` function might not working as if ACF is causing somehow an infinite loop in Elementor. That is why you have to use `get_post_meta`.

Here is a suggestion. In the assumption, you have "Product" and "Supplier" as custom post types and "Product" has as a custom taxonomy (category) "Supplier". "Supplier" has an Advanced Custom Field with `supplier_cat`.
To show all to the supplier related products you can select in the Query section of the Posts Widget of Elementor:

```
Source: Product
Query ID: my-custom-query
```

With this code in your theme's `function.php` file:

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/my-custom-query', function( $query ) {

    $postid = get_the_ID();
    $supplier_cat = get_post_meta( $postid, 'supplier_cat', true );
    $tax_query = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'supplier_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $supplier_cat,
        )
    );
    $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );

} );
```

Reference of this action hook:
https://developers.elementor.com/custom-query-filter/